# Finding the PDF given the CDF

Tags: distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

How can I find the PDF (probability density function) of a distribution given the CDF (cumulative distribution function)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difficulty. If the functional form is known just take the derivative otherwise take differences. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am guessing the question is about multivariate case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As user28 said in comments above, the pdf is the first derivative of the cdf for a continuous random variable, and the difference for a discrete random variable.

In the continuous case, wherever the cdf has a discontinuity the pdf has an atom.  Dirac delta "functions" can be used to represent these atoms.

Comment: There is a nice online textbook by Pishro-Nik [here](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_2_delta_function.php) showing this more explicitly.

Comment: Does something similar hold for multivariate case? (I found the answer [here](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~cfgranda/pages/DSGA1002_fall16/material/multivariate_random_variables.pdf) page 9). $f(\mathbf x) = \frac{\partial^n F(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_1 \dots \partial x_n}$

Comment: Would you mind give an example that a cdf has a discontinuity?

Comment: @Paul are you wrong in saying above that the discrete pdf is simply the difference of the cdf, $F(x_2) - F(x_1)$? shouldn't it be $\frac{F(x_2) - F(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$?

Comment: @develarist You are correct in that this is imprecise.  If the discrete outcomes are consecutive integers, then the difference is sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

Let $F(x)$ denote the cdf; then you can always approximate the pdf of a continuous random variable  by calculating $$ \frac{F(x_2) - F(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1},$$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are on either side of the point where you want to know the pdf and the distance $|x_2 - x_1|$ is small.

Comment: Thats the same as taking the derivative, but just more inaccurate so why would you do it?

Comment: This would be the approach when the CDF is only approximated empirically. It gives lousy estimates of the PDF, though.

Comment: Given CDF percentile values, is there a better way to calculate PDF from these discrete values ?

Comment: In this case, are all x from x1 to xn sorted in an ascending order first so that it is always xn>x(n-1)>x(n-2)>…..x3>x2>x1?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating the CDF does not always help, consider equation:

```
 F(x) = (1/4) + ((4x - x*x) / 8)    ...    0 <= x < 2,
```

Differentiating it you'll get:

```
((2 - x) / 4)
```

substituting 0 in it gives value (1/2) which is clearly wrong as P(x = 0) is clearly (1 / 4).

Instead what you should do is calculate difference between F(x) and lim(F(x - h)) as h tends to 0 from positive side of (x).

Comment: (-1) Because this CDF *does* have a derivative, the random variable is continuous and *clearly*  $P(x=0)=0.$  You appear to be confusing densities with probabilities.