# How to obtain the probability density function from its cumulants?

Tags: density-function, approximation, moment-generating-function, cumulants

Let $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, $ be the sequence of [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) of a probability density function $p(x)$. How can we reconstruct $p(x)$ from its cumulants?

P.S. If it helps, you can assume that $p(x)$ is of bounded support in a finite interval $[a,b]$. Also, it is implicit that all the cumulants of $p(x)$ are finite.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781

Answer (score 2):

The cumulants can be obtained from the cumulant generating function (cgf), which is the logarithm of the moment generating function. The cgf can be used to approximate the density function via the saddlepoint approximation, see [How does saddlepoint approximation work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781).  Other ideas can be found at [Constructing a continuous distribution to match $m$ moments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments)  and [the scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cumulants).

Some examples:

- [Generic sum of Gamma random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/generic-sum-of-gamma-random-variables/137318#137318)
- [Bound for weighted sum of Poisson random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183313/bound-for-weighted-sum-of-poisson-random-variables/183355#183355)

Answer (score 1):

Although the closed-form expression for the PDF cannot be found from cumulants, approximation of the quantile function (also known as the inverse CDF) can be numerically evaluated using the [Cornish–Fisher expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornish%E2%80%93Fisher_expansion). The CDF values can then be obtained by transposing the quantile function and differentiating them numerically to obtain the PDF [see "Finding the PDF given the CDF"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/189/408593).

Comment: This answer would be better if it provided more details of the derivations or calculations mentioned, at least in outline.

Answer (score 0):

The cumulant generating function is the log of the moment generating function. It is possible then to characterize the distribution with the cumulants.

This in turn can help you obtain the density function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant